# Css files for individual pages(home/product/category/user profile/login)

Tags: magento2

I'm looking to create a theme from scratch and what I want to do is create .css files individually for each individual page and only load them specifically for that given page.

I believe this is the best option to optimize a page rendering's speed, correct me if I'm wrong.

What is the correct way of including each of these files for the given pages?

```
home/product/category/user profile/login/checkout

home.css | product.css | category.css | etc..
```

If I missed a component please let me know.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

1. Now the first question is whether you are willing to do CSS merge or not if yes then it's no point to do.
2. If you are willing to install a third-party extension then they add CSS in the default.xml file.
3. See focus on the js part if you are able to reduce and make it load faster.

That's what I feel that there is too much work with less satisfaction.

Instead of that override .less file from a parent prevent the repetitive declaration of style

Might this help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Critical CSS, even normal sites use this term, so you can google what it is in case you don't know: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css-critical-path.html